# Importing a CSV file in Matlab using fopen/fclose that has comments of varying lengths with no specific preceding character

Tags: matlab

I need to import a CSV file into matlab that has ~160,000 rows and 25 columns. The 33'rd column has commentary on some rows. The comments are of varying lengths, and are textual, for example, a comment might read (without the quotes around it) "mortality due to suppression" (it is a forest inventory database).

The first four columns represent the site and time of the tree measurements.

The ultimate goal of the program is to consolidate the information in the file into unique smaller files, each one which will hold all trees' data on a unique combination of site and time.

At the moment the import strategy I am using is

```
fid = fopen('TP07303_v1.csv','r');
tline = fgetl(fid);

% split the title line (header) and call it A
A(1,:) = regexp(tline,'\,','split');


% parse and read the rest of the file
ctr = 1;
while(~feof(fid))
    if ischar(tline)
        ctr = ctr + 1;
            tline = fgetl(fid);
            A(ctr, :) = regexp(tline,'\,','split');
    else
        break;
    end
end

fclose(fid);
```

But when I get to the first line with a comment, it snags. I don't need the comments for anything I am doing and am happy to just not import that column entirely. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `textscan` with what will admittedly be a long format string? You can use `%*[^\n]` at the end of your format string to skip the remaining columns...

Comment: " has ~160,000 rows and 25 columns. The 33'rd column has "  Which is it?  does it have 25, or 33 columns?  Can you post of couple of rows of example data?

Answer (score 0):

I am also confused about the number of columns (25 or 33+?), but if the number of commas on each line varies that is why you are having problems. Is that why you are not using dlmread?

Also the ischar seems redundant since tline will always be a char, unless you are at the end of the file, but you are looping on that condition. In effect, you are checking the same thing twice in a row.

```
while(~feof(fid))
    ctr       = ctr + 1;
    tline     = fgetl(fid);
    tmp       = regexp(tline,'\,','split');
    % make sure to not assign more than 25 elements to this row of A
    A(ctr, :) = tmp(1:25);
    if numel(tmp)>25
        % do something with the rest
    end
end
```

and there would never be less than 25 elements right?